# How to deal with the aggregate root without repository, when using Spring Data Common to publish domain events

Tags: java, spring-data, publish-subscribe, ddd-repositories, domain-events

The logic is: publish an event to notify closing a netty channel. Before, through `DomainEventPublish`, I publish the event at domain service, application service, or `catch`. Now, I found that it was wrong because only aggregate root can publish domain event.

I plan to refactor the way of publishing domain events to using Spring Data Common. I can design an aggregate root named `ChannelToClose`, and with a method that will register the `NeedClose` event, but I can't publish the registered events. Spring Data Common publishes the registered events only when executing `save()` of a repository, so **I don't know how to publish events when aggregate root doesn't need to be persisted**.

This is the comment of `org.springframework.data.domain.DomainEvents`:

> DomainEvents can be used on methods of aggregate roots managed by Spring Data repositories to publish the events returned by that method as Spring application events.

Comment: Hi Oliver, welcome to SO. Please ask only one question per post. You can edit your question, remove one of the questions and make it a separate posting. Feel free to leave a link to the new question in the comments.

Comment: @JensSchauder Thank you

Comment: I have moved the second question to a new posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52073819

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

Just call `save` anyway or manually register events using an `ApplicationEventPublisher`.

Some background:

The underlying problem is that JPA doesn't really lend it well to DDD.

Since it saves everything that changed inside the session there is no easy hook to put the required event handling in.

One might consider inspecting the session itself or relying on JPAs lifecycle events, but these are based on entities with no (clear) way to identify the Aggregate Root it belongs to.

Imagine an `Order` of which you change the `quantity` in one of its `LineItem`s. JPA will fire an event for the `LineItem` but not for the `Order`, but the `Order` is the Aggregate Root that should fire the events.

So either way, it is a leaky abstraction. 
Spring Data went with relying on the save-method which works for most (all?) other stores.
These stores most of the time have a much clearer way to identify Aggregates.
MongoDb for example has Documents which pretty much are a 1:1 fit to Aggregates.

Comment: I still don't fully learn about domain events, but I have confirmed that domain events should only be published by aggregation, and the aggregation is logically necessary to have a save operation. If I don't need aggregation to be physically persistent, then I only need to adjust the implementation of the repository.

Comment: Hi, So I came across your post. I have a question though. You mentioned that MongoDB and Aggregates are a 1:1 fit. So does that mean that we generally shouldn't make a different repository class for storing aggregate roots in mongoDB? Also wouldn't we have to add `@Document` annotation on top of our `Aggregate` which would leak infrastructure code in our Domain Model?

Comment: Please create a proper question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Hi, as a matter of fact I did have a question on this posted but stumbled on this answer. I've edited the question a bit to explain in detail. [You can find the question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61632788/explicitly-call-the-domain-events-of-an-aggregate-root-spring). Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution to this problem is described at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/1727 :

> My current solution is to force that the save method must be
> explicitly called at the end of the service. I used a Hibernate
> interceptor that was inserted into the preFlush, which throws an
> exception when it finds that the aggregate has some domain events.
>
> I found that the issue has become resolved. Can I ask if it is solved
> or not a problem?
>
> Also, I can't seem to close the issue, please close it

Credits go to https://jira.spring.io/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=teclxl