# Can it register an domain event in the constructor of aggregate root, when using Spring Data Common

Tags: domain-events, spring-data-commons

The aggregate will be created by some `application service`, not by another aggregate.

Like this

```
SomeAggregate aggregate = new SomeAggregate();
repo.save(aggregate);
```

The expectation is that the `aggregate` is saved and one `SomeAggregateCreated` event is published when the application service is over. I have tested it, it is not always effective, sometimes the event is not registered immediately after the constructor is executed.

This is the teacher class:

```
public class Teacher extends AbstractAggregateRoot<Teacher> {

    public Teacher() {
        registerEvent(new TeacherAdded(id, name));
    }
}
```

This is the `TeacherAdded`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
public class TeacherAdded extends AbstractDomainEvent {
    private TeacherId teacherId;    
    private String name;
}
```

This is `AbstractDomainEvent` and `DomainEvent`

```
@Getter
@ToString()
@EqualsAndHashCode()
public abstract class AbstractDomainEvent implements DomainEvent {
    protected Date occurredOn;

    public AbstractDomainEvent() {
        this(new Date());
    }

    public AbstractDomainEvent(Date occurredOn) {
        this.occurredOn = occurredOn != null ? occurredOn : new Date();
    }

    @Override
    public Date occurredOn() {
        return occurredOn;
    }    
}

public interface DomainEvent {
    public Date occurredOn();
}
```

The `AbstractAggregateRoot` is copied from `org.springframework.data.domain.AbstractAggregateRoot<A>`, and the `hasCapturedEvent` method is added for testing.

```
public boolean hasCapturedEvent(DomainEvent event) {
    return domainEvents.contains(event);
}
```

If I run this:

```
// ...
TeacherAdded teacherAdded = new TeacherAdded(teacherId, teacherName);
Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
assertTrue(teacher.hasCapturedEvent(teacherAdded));
```

It sometimes fails and sometimes succeeds.

Comment: What do you mean by "register a domain event"? I assume something is happening in the constructor of `SomeAggregate`? Can you show that constructor?

Comment: public class Teacher extends AbstractAggregateRoot<Teacher>

Comment: public Teacher() {registerEvent(new TeacherAdded(id, name));}

Comment: Teacher teacher = new Teacher();assertTrue(teacher.hasCapturedEvent(teacherAdded));  **Most pass, sometimes fail**

Comment: I edited the question to include the source code you posted in the comments. Please, review and edit if necessary.

Comment: There are still some pieces missing: `teacherAdded` is never defined, neither is `hasCapturedEvent`

I'm currently suspecting that this might be related to a broken implement of `equals` and/or `hashCode`

Comment: I have added the source code

Comment: Now I know why my test has occasionally failed. It should always fail, because `occurredOn` is one of the criteria for equality but it is generated in real time. I need to improve the `hasCapturedEvent` method.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is `yes`. The domain events registered by the constructor can be published and listened normally. They are the same as the events registered by the usual method.

The test I provided in the problem description is defective. After modifying `AbstractDomainEvent.hasCapturedEvent` and its associated code, the test can pass.

This is new `AbstractDomainEvent.hasCapturedEvent` and test method.

```
    public boolean hasCapturedEvent(DomainEvent event, long occurredOnAdjustment) {
        if (occurredOnAdjustment <= 0) {
            return this.domainEvents.contains(event);
        } else {
            return this.domainEvents.stream().anyMatch(eventOnStream -> {
                return eventOnStream.equalsExcludedOccurTime(event)
                    && System.currentTimeMillis() - eventOnStream.occurredOn().getTime() <= occurredOnAdjustment;
            });
        }
    }

        TeacherAdded teacherAdded = new TeacherAdded(teacherId, teacherName);
        Teacher teacher = new Teacher();
        assertTrue(teacher.hasCapturedEvent(teacherAdded, 1000L));
```

This is new `TeacherAdded`.

```
public interface DomainEvent {
    public Date occurredOn();

    public default boolean equalsExcludedOccurTime(DomainEvent other) {
        return false;
    }
}

@lombok...
public class TeacherAdded extends AbstractDomainEvent {
    private TeacherId teacherId;    
    private String name;

    @Override
    public boolean equalsExcludedOccurTime(DomainEvent other) {
        if (!(other instanceof TeacherAdded)) {
            return false;
        } else {
            TeacherAdded other2 = (TeacherAdded)other;
            return Objects.equals(teacherId, other2.teacherId)
                && Objects.equals(name, other2.name);
        }
    }
}
```