# Domain Events with Spring Boot and MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design

I am working with `DDD` and `Spring` using `MongoDB`.

Now the since `MongoDB` is a `DocumentDB` and no schema validations are present, The `AggregateRoot` and the Document class that gets stored in the MongoDB are two different classes and the `Repository` translates content between those two classes while reading and writing data to `database`.

Since the Root entity class is different from the class being stored to DB, Spring doesn't trigger the `DomainEvents` of the `AggregateRoot`.

- Is there a way I can get trigger the events of the Root entity from the Repository after storing the data to the database? (maybe by an explicit invoke)
- Since the MongoDB and Aggregates are a 1:1 fit. So does that mean that we generally shouldn't make a two different classes one as `AggregateRoot` and another the Document Class for storing aggregate roots in mongoDB? Wouldn't we have to add @Document annotation on top of our Aggregate which would leak infrastructure code in our Domain Model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while I figured out the solution, from the upvotes I believe others are facing the same problem, here is the solution:

#### Question: Can we trigger an explicit invoke for the Domain Events?

**Answer:** Yes, we can. In `SpringBoot` we can use/`Autowire` the `ApplicationEventPublisher` interface and then call `publishEvent(event)` method.

If you're making a separate class for Db collection and Aggregate you would need to expose out your `DomainEvents` and a method for `ClearingDomainEvents` in your aggregate since the `AbstractAggregateRoot<T>` has these methods as `protected`. Below is an example of raising an event on creation:

```
public class MyAggregateRootClass extends AbstractAggregateRoot<MyAggregateRootClass> 
{
    public MyAggregateRootClass(String property1, String property2) {

        // set the fields here
        registerEvent(new MyAggregateRootCreated(someArgs));
    }

    public Collection<Object> getDomainEvents() {
        return super.domainEvents();
    }

    public void clearDomainEvents() {
        super.clearDomainEvents();
    }
}
```

The Repository Code would look like:

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor // using lombok here, you can create a constructor if you want
public class MyAggregateRepository {

    private final ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    private final AggregateMongoRepository repository;

    public void save(MyAggregateRootClass aggToSave) {

        AggregateDao convertedAgg = new AggregateDao(aggToSave);

        repository.save(convertedAgg);

        // raise all the domain events
        for (Object event : aggToSave.getDomainEvents())
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);

        // clear them since all events have been raised
        aggToSave.clearDomainEvents();
    }
}
```

---

#### So does that mean that we generally shouldn't make two different classes, one as `AggregateRoot` and another the Document Class for storing aggregate roots in `mongoDB`?

**Answer**: No, that does not mean that. The goal of the `DDD` would be to separate `infrastructure` from the `Domain` and keep the `Domain` agnostic of all infrastructure code. If they both are the same then below is the impact:

- Having the `@Document` annotation on your `Aggregate Class` would make you change your `Domain` if you're switching frameworks or swapping `Mongodb` with `SQL`.
- In the future in case your DB schema needs to change, you would have to either also change your aggregate class or you would have to setup the adapter classes.
- Since the domain should only change if there is a change in business requirements and not because of `infrastructure dependencies`, creeping in the `infrastructure annotations` into the `AggregateRoot` would not be the best way

So when can you actually just get away with using the same class for Aggregate and Db Collection?

If you do want to just keep it simple and use the same class for both and not create a separate class then make sure you're sure about the below:

- If you're absolutely sure that you're never going to switch DBs or change frameworks.
- You have a simple Domain Model and you don't need to store `Entities` of the `Aggregate` in a separate collection and you there is no possibility that those `Entities` would ever grow into their own `Aggregates`

In the end it depends. Feel free to drop in comments and I'll try my best to answer all of them, quite active on stack.

Comment: You can use Monogo Template to interact with Mongodb. Or You can use xml configuration. No need to use the different class for Domain Model and Data Model and no need to use annotation on domain model class.

Comment: @AshwaniTiwari you're right using `MongoTemplate` would allow us not to use the `@Document` annotation but later if the db schema changes you'll have to change your Domain Model too if we don't have two different classes for `DomainModel` and `DataModel`. Although it's okay for `RDBMS` because any change have to be performed using Migrations, but for `Non-RDBMS` it can lead to small bugs here and there, compromising the integrity of the `DomainModel`.